# Creating a code that computes the distance between two properties given northings and eastings

Tags: python, distance, coordinates, pandas

I was given a file with different properties in different sheets containing coordinates for each corners. I need to create a program that computes the distance between two lots. I'm not sure how to approach making it, do I just need to compute for the centroid of each property and then use the distance formula? Or do I need to use each point corners?

This is my code so far.

```
import pandas as pd
class Lot:
    def __init__(self,name,vertices):
        self.name = name #name of the lot (in the sheets it's A1, A2 ..)
        self.vertices = vertices #list of tuples (eastings,northings)
        self.centroid = self.__getCentroid()

    def __getCentroid(self):
        '''A method that computes the centroid of the lot and returns a tuple containing the Eastings and Northings of the centroid.
        Used to determine the centroid attribute.'''
        self.e = 0
        self.n = 0
        count = len(self.vertices)
        for e in self.vertices:
            self.e += e[0]
        for n in self.vertices:
            self.n += n[1]
        centroid = (self.e/count , self.n/count)
        return centroid
    
    def distanceTo(self,other_Lot): #float ouput
       '''A method that computes the distance between the lot and the lot given'''
       pass
    
    #def nearest(lotList:List):
    #    '''Determines the nearest lot from a list of lots'''
```

Comment: The only person who can answer that question is the person who asked it.  Do they want the distance between property centroids (even if the centroid is not within the propety)?  Do they want the minimum distance between the properties?  If the latter, then just using the corner points is not sufficient.  Imagine two squares placed next to each other and then rotate the right-hand square by 45 degrees (so it is now more of a square diamond).  The nearest point of the  left-hand (non-rotated) square 
 to the other one is half way along one of its edges, not any of its corners.

Comment: Do you have to compute the centroid and distance yourself? If not, consider geopandas instead of pandas

Comment: @SonofaBeach this is the instruction given and we can not ask further questions : "Computes the distance between the lot and the lot given".

Comment: @user2856 we were told that we can only use pandas that's why i didn't try and use geopandas even though that is more convenient

Comment: With that limited information, I would assume that they want the shortest distance between the two polygons, not the distance between centroids.  But it's up to your interpretation, I guess.  Finding the shortest distance between two polygons is non-trivial if you don't have a geometry library to use.  Is this an education assignment question?

Comment: @SonofaBeach it is an exercise yes. I was just wondering why would the method getCentroid is relevant if it's not going to be used for other things so I connected it to the distance. How does one find the shortest distance between polygons if there are different number of vertices/corners?